# how to create build definition on Visual studio Team Services for a web role to send package to a drop location

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-roles, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have loaded my web role project to Visual Studio Team Services. In the VSTS portal I created a new build definition. I added tasks Visual Studio Build and Publish Artifacts.

Task Visual Studio Build
MSBuild Arguments: **/t:Publish /p:PublishDir=PublishDir\ /p:TargetProfile=Cloud**

Publish Aritifact:drop 
Path to Publish : **$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)**

However after I run this definition I go to "Artifacts">"Explore" there is nothing in the drop location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use worker roles but the deployment sequence should be the same (unless you're talking about web apps and not roles)
In build arguments we target the ccproj and add that **/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=$(targetProfile) /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutputPath=bin\ /p:PublishDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)\\"**
Then we have a deploy cloud service step with that as arguments for the packages **$(build.stagingDirectory)*.cspkg** and **$(build.stagingDirectory)*.cscfg**
Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for the help but with one small modification /t:Publish /p:PublishDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\" /p:TargetProfile=Cloud. publishDir has a 2 back slashes at the end or else it throws error.

Comment: Thanks it originally had two \ at the end but one somehow disappeared in stack's formatting